# Use sorted listbox to select first record in list, not in database

Tags: ms-access, vba

In an Access form, I'm using a listbox to select the record I want to view (which is working fine, manually).  The listbox is populated with names in a query that sorts them alphabetically, and that works fine.

Using VBA, I have the listbox selecting the first item in the box both when the form first loads, and when the user clicks a button to requery (the user can narrow down the list of names, by age, on the form itself.

When the form first loads, it has no trouble loading the record of the first item in the listbox.  When the Search button is pressed, the form loads the first record in the database that matches the criteria, even if it doesn't match the first item in the listbox.

This is my code for both events:

```
Private Sub btnSearch_Click()
  DoCmd.RunMacro "Requery", 1

  Me.listControl.SetFocus
  Me.listControl.Selected(0) = True
  Me.listControl = Me.listControl.ItemData(0)
End Sub


Private Sub Form_Load()
  DoCmd.RunMacro "Requery", 1

  Me.listControl.SetFocus
  Me.listControl.Selected(0) = True
  Me.listControl = Me.listControl.ItemData(0)
End Sub
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What does the macro do?

Comment: It requeries the query that populates the form.  It only has one action, which is Requery, without a Control specified.

Comment: And in which event is the loading of the selected record?

Comment: That's a setting you can select when you drop a listbox into a form. http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/enable-users-to-find-a-record-by-selecting-a-value-from-a-list-HA010274375.aspx

Comment: I'm not sure why you're Requerying your form in either sub - Requerying is to load the source dataset again in case there were changes.  Sounds like you want to navigate to an existing record in the dataset.  Is there any code on the AfterUpdate event on the listbox (I'm not sure how the wizard implements this functionality)?  If there is, I think you could rip out the existing code on your button and copy/call that code directly.  Generally, if you manipulate controls in VBA, the events you usually think would be associated with them don't fire.

Comment: I'm requerying because the query has a Between criteria for the age -- it defaults to 0-100, but there are controls on the form the user can use to set the age to something narrower (or broader, but it's a database for actors so it's unlikely anyone will be older than 100).  There might be a cleaner way to do it, but I don't know how.  I'll look at the AfterUpdate events -- there is one, but it's only a single Action that could probably be replicated in code.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't know this feature and tried it at work today. It generates an embedded macro. It is also only a one-way toggling, i.e. the listbox controls the form but not vice versa. I guess that's where your problems started in the first place.

You will have to do the following:

1. Keep ListBox and Form recordsets equivalent, i.e. if you filter one, filter the other also. You will run into crazy situations, if not.
2. Throw away the embedded macro and use the [FindFirst method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/office/ff194787%28v=office.15%29.aspx) in your AfterUpdate event (best in the module of the form, not in the listbox props)
3. Wire up the ListBox so it always shows the selected record in the form by selecting the correlated row in the form's Form_Current event
4. Catch an endless loop by doing 2 and 3 only if the ids of both are not the same

If you can't get it to work, post the code where you are doing the filtering (and explain how) and I'll have a look tomorrow.

Comment: Does FindFirst go to the first record in the query by record ID, or by whatever record is first after the Sort?

Comment: With a unique ID- who cares? But AFAIK it respects the order of the recordset. Just try it out.